# Modify AccessLog for custom requests in Istio

Tags: istio, open-telemetry, envoyproxy, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

We are following the standard AccessLog format:

```
[%START_TIME%] "%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%"
%RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION%
%RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% "%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%" "%REQ(USER-AGENT)%"
"%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%" "%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%" "%UPSTREAM_HOST%"\n
```

I would like to modify this format for a custom request (.../exit) to not log sensitive data. Is it possible to filter the route this way?

Init code:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: ***
  namespace: ***
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      service.istio.io/canonical-name: ***
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
        vhost:
          name: "*"
          route:
            name: "/exit"
            action: ANY
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
            typed_config:
              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog"
              path: /dev/stdout
              format: "[%START_TIME%] \"%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%\" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% \n"
```

Anyone has an idea how can I fix this to filter out the /exit requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the Telemetry resource - I think you can match the specific path with CEL expression in the [`filter` field](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/telemetry/#AccessLogging-Filter).

You can find the list of attributes you can use in the CEL expressions here: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/advanced/attributes

Example Telemetry resource with filter:

```yaml
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: mesh-default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  accessLogging:
    - providers:
      - name: privateLoggingProvider
      filter:
        expression: "request.url_path.contains('/ip')"
```

The `privateLoggingProvider` is set in the mesh config:

```yaml
  meshConfig:
    extensionProviders:
    - name: privateLoggingProvider
      envoyFileAccessLog:
        path: /dev/stdout
        logFormat:
            text: "your custom format here"
```

Note that if you know the workloads you want to restrict or change the formats for, you can use the selectors in the Telemetry resource to target the workloads specifically (instead of applying it to all workloads/mesh).

Comment: Note you'd probably have to create a second access logger (in IstioOperator), specify the access logging format there and configure it to be enabled only for the specific routes.

Comment: I have tried this and it works. But I can only enable or disable the logs. Is it possible to change it dinamically with the Telemetry API? (probably not)
I couldn't figure it out have can I have a different log format for a specific route (.../.../exit)

Comment: I updated the above answer as the comments here don't render multi-line YAML well :)